# Check constraint between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I have two tables, let's call them A and B. They have One to many relationship.

**Table A**

```
Trxid int,
TotalAmount decimal(10,2)
```

**Table B**

```
Trxid int,
TblBcol Varchar,
Amount decimal(10,2)
```

Table B contains breakup details for Table A.

**My requirement :** sum of `Amount` column of Table B should be equal to Table A's `TotalAmount` column for each `trxid`.

Is there any constraint available to achieve this or is there any other way?

Comment: One option is to replace Table A with a view.

Comment: Other option may be create a trigger on `TableB` which inserts or update respective row in `TableA`. but the idea suggested by @destination-data is more appropriate.

Comment: @destination-data  Thanks for response. Table A contains other columns also. Moving them to Table B will result redundancy.

Comment: @Pramod thanks. but every row insert of Table B is checked against total amount and results validation fails.

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me - is A.TotalAmount filled separately or must it always be sum of B.Amount? If it is filled separately and is used only to check document validity, then you should not fail check while inserting rows into B - otherwise you just cannot insert anything, unless it contains full amount. You have to validate entire document afterwards, not SQL task (but can use SQL procedure).

Comment: Alternative - create computed column with function, see example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13488822/create-computed-column-using-data-from-another-table#13488881)

Comment: @KonstantinTaranov: I am not sure that a computed function would work here. IIRC you can only use UDFs in a computed column if they are deterministic (i.e. if they always return the same value for the same input values). Since the function would have to query another table, SQL Server is likely not going to categorize it as a deterministic function, and therefore it couldn't be used in the computed column specification. (But to be honest, this is from memory; I haven't actually tried.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possible solutions for this. Choose according to your preferences.

1. **Get rid of the redundancy.** Having amount columns in both tables that have to match is probably not necessary. It might be enough to have only one amount column, so there would never be a need in the first place to keep them "in sync". You have a foreign key relationship between the two tables, so your database clients can always `JOIN` them to "attach" the amount column from one table to the other for the purpose of querying.
2. **Remove `Amount` from `B` and create a view.** If your client requires a table containing the same information that is in your current `B` table, but they only query that table, you could replace it with a view:

   ```
   CREATE VIEW B WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
   SELECT BWithoutAmount.Trxid, BWithoutAmount.TblBcol, A.TotalAmount AS Amount
   FROM BWithoutAmount JOIN A ON BWithoutAmount.Trxid = A.Trxid;
   ```

   This assumes that there is a base table `BWithoutAmount` that replaces your current `B`, but doesn't have the `Amount` column. The `B` view takes the place of your current `B` base table.
3. **Define a `TRIGGER` on tables `A` and `B`.** Their task would be to update the `Amount` column in `B` so it matches the amount from the corresponding row in `A`. The triggers need to run in the following cases:

   - When a row in `A` is updated.
   - When a row in `B` is inserted.

   The FK constraint and `ON DELETE CASCADE` should take care of the rest.

Comment: Point No. 3 will fit with my requirement. Thanks for your valuable suggestions.